Problems deploying healthcare in a dockerized frappe development installation
I'm following this tutorial to set a dev environment:
After having installed ERPNEXT, I use the admindashboard to create the first user (besides Administrator).
Then, I do:
$ bench get-app healthcare --branch version-15
(It warns Ignoring dependencies of healthcare. To install dependencies use --resolve-deps
Installing healthcare)
and
$ bench --site development.localhost install-app healthcare
And I get:
Error: No module named 'frappe.core.doctype.medical_department'
Any idea? I guess the error comes from dependencies or versions mismatches, but honestly, I have no other clues.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What code have you actually written?  If the eventual error suggests a missing dependency, and the install command indicates it's not installing dependencies, does the advice in the warning help?

Hi David, thank you for your prompt response. The linked tutorial provides all the steps needed to replicate my situation. If you follow the tutorial, when you reach the 'Setup first bench' section, skip ahead to 'Setup bench / new site using script,' as that's the approach I took.
Let me know if you'd like any further refinements.
Regarding the dependencies, not exactly. You can use:
bench get-app healthcare --branch version-15 --resolve-deps
However, this leads to other errors. I'll give it another try anyway.

The error I get when I use the bench get-app healthcare --branch version-15 --resolve-deps is:
ERROR: Invalid frappe path: erpnext
Erpnext it's already installed...

I finally managed to fix things. You need to 'migrate' with the bench command, before bench start. I thought that was done automatically when you bench install an app.
